# Use DataBinding in Fragment with different package of related Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I have a collection of fragment that I utilze in many apps, so they are all in foo.bar.components and standolone project, one of them use DataBinding in layout, problems occur when I use a fragment within an Activity in different packagake like for.bar.app

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar.app/foo.bar.app.Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: foo.bar.app.databinding.FragmentFooBindingImpl cannot be cast to foo.bar.components.databinding.FragmentFooBinding
```

I do binding in fragment as:

```java
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FragmentFooBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);
    binding.setItem(Item);
    return binding.getRoot();
  }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Add your `fragment_foo.xml`

Comment: and your import statements